# Handling token based authorization in Node Js

Tags: node.js, token

I am new to Node Js. Before, I worked with Laravel API. In Laravel I handle the the Endpoints using the token saved in the database to use the certain endpoints . For example : `localhost:3000/api/users/getall?token=1234`. If there is no token passed, the API says `Unauthorized access and no token provided`. If the token is invalid then the system will say `Invalid token`. AS such way, how can I validate the endpoints using the token saved in the Mongo Database?

**User Model**

```
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    fname : {type: String, required: true, max: 25, trim: false},
    uname : {type: String, required: true, max: 25, trim: false},
    password : {type: String, required: true},
    token : {type: String, required: true},
    role: {type: String, required: true}, //0 - admin, 1 - counter
},
{
    timestamps:true
});

mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('User');
```

The following user getAll endpoint can only accessed by admin

**getAll endpoint**

```
router.get("/", function (req, res, next)
{
    User.find()
    .select('fname uname')
    .exec()
    .then(docs => {
        return res.send(setting.status("User details retrieval successfully", true, docs))
    .catch(err => {
        return res.send(setting.status("Error in retrieving user details",false, err))
    });
    });
});

})
```

The above getAll route now can be accessed by admin and counter also. And It is not checks the token from the database(I.e : can accessed with out token).

How can I used token check and validate?

Comment: are you familiar with middleware?

Comment: no, I am new to node js

Answer (score 1):

Before doing anything, get the token from the query params and validate it. If it's not valid, just send a '**401 Unauthorized**' status, or whatever response you like.

```
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {      
  const token = req.query.token
  if (!isValid(token)) return res.status(401).end()

  User.find()
    .select('fname uname')
    .exec()
    .then(docs => {
      return res.send(setting.status("User details retrieval successfully", true, docs))
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return res.send(setting.status("Error in retrieving user details",false, err))
    });
})
```

Make sure you return explicitly or the execution will continue. Or just use an `if-else` statement.

Comment: What is `isValid(token)` in `if` statement ? And how can I check?

Comment: You should own the implementation of `isValid`. I don't know what type of tokens you are using.

Comment: I am using `jwt` token

Comment: And I think it does not check the `role`

Comment: In that case, if you're only interested if it is valid I'd suggest using the `jsonwebtoken` package and the [verify](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/blob/master/README.md#jwtverifytoken-secretorpublickey-options-callback) method

Answer (score 0):

You can use middleware to validate requests. On server.js

```html
//validate requests
app.use ('/', function (req, res, next) {
  if (
    // except the public requests (for login ...)
    req.originalUrl.indexOf ('/public') > -1
  ) {
    next ();
  } else {
    if (
      // Compare with your token
      req.query &&
      req.query.hasOwnProperty ('access_token') &&
      req.query.access_token === 'YOUR_TOKEN'
    ) {
      next ();
    } else {
      // STOP
      return res.json ({
        success: false,
        message: 'Failed to authenticate.',
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: What is `next()` in both `if` statements?

Comment: How can I validate the `role` ?

Comment: please search for your next question or create a new question if you can not find what you are looking for.

Comment: For understanding about next() and middleware, you can read https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html.